# Remote connection to MySql on Azure fails

Tags: mysql, windows, azure

**EDIT 2:**

the problem was solved by opening the 3306 port on Azure portal. I went to the `VM > Networking` and added an `Inbound Rule`. The connection from the outside immediately started working.

I have MySql 5.7 installed on a windows server 2012 virtual machine on Azure. Port 3306 is opened, and I run the following to allow remote access:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON db_name.* TO 'user'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I restarted MySql service and tried to connect again. But still the same error:

```
MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'servername.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com' (4)
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: I looked at both the links in the "Duplicate" message. But it looks like `my.ini` on the machine doesn't have any of the issues. Specifically there is no

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
# skip-external-locking
```

that could be commented out. There is no mention of any ip address in the file. The only vaguely relevant part is this

```
[mysqld]

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# shared-memory

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
```

So I still don't have an answer.

Comment: How did you check that port 3306 is open?

Comment: I created an `inbound rule` in the `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security` app.

Comment: I run `netstat -an`: `TCP    [::]:3000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING`

Comment: Before you write that ubuntu is not azure or windows, pls note that mysql configuration allowing remote access is OS independent.

Comment: @Shadow the answers in the duplicate link are not helpful here. I edited the question with more info.

Comment: @Eddy did you find any solution ?